# Get min and max from array of dates with month integer and year only ("n-Y" format)

Tags: php, date, max, min, date-comparison

I have a date array containing only month and year ..I want to get min and max date from this array.

```
$dates = array('1-2018','5-2019','10-2018','5-2020');
```

The min result should be `1-2018`.

The max result should be `5-2020`.

Answer (score 2):

use usort. usort need a function for compare. A string with only month-year can not parse with strtotime. With a Day (i use simple the 1-)  returns strtotime a correct timestamp. This funktion is for a ascendig sort. For descendig sort you must only switch $a and $b.
I have add some values to the array for a better test.

```
<?php
$dates = array('1-2018','5-2019','10-2018','5-2020','9-1978','6-2001');

usort($dates, function($a,$b){ return strtotime('1-'.$a) <=> strtotime('1-'.$b);});

echo "<pre>".var_export($dates, true)."\n";

echo "Min: ".reset($dates)."\n";
echo "Max: ".end($dates)."\n";
```

Edit: The minimum is the first value from the array, the maximum is the last value.

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '9-1978',
  1 => '6-2001',
  2 => '1-2018',
  3 => '10-2018',
  4 => '5-2019',
  5 => '5-2020',
)
 Min: 9-1978
 Max: 5-2020
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/lZocQ

Answer (score 1):

You should transform all your string in `DateTime` object with `DateTime::createFromFormat` [method](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

```
$dates = array_map(function($date){
  return DateTime::createFromFormat('m-Y',$date);
}, $dates);
```

Then sort them with `sort` function

```
sort($dates);
```

Comment: Why do we need user function to sort them?

Comment: I do not know how sort works with dates. Maybe, `sort` work perfectly.

Comment: You can easily test it, since you already wrote the code. Just execute and see, e.g. https://3v4l.org/qHSIe